# Iterate Folder Name in batch Files

Tags: batch-file

Currently I am iterating all files in a folder, currently I am in `Sample` folder and I am doing it like this:

```
@echo off

for  /R %%a in ("*") do (
@echo %%a
 )

pause
```

And it lists files like this:

```
C:\Users\-----\Desktop\Sample\mybat.bat
C:\Users\-----\Desktop\Sample\bin\1.dll
C:\Users\-----\Desktop\Sample\content\themes\2.css
```

What I want is to list the name but starting from current folder where I put the `.bat` file, i. e., it should look like this:

```
Sample\mybat.bat
Sample\bin\1.dll
Sample\content\themes\2.css
```

Comment: Manipulate each full path returned in the loop by removing the %CD% variable from the beginning of each.

Comment: A simple `dir /B/S/A-D` will get you the pretty same output. Compos suggestion will require string substitution and in a (code block) also delayed expansion.

Comment: My mistake @LotPings then, I thought that using **`/S`**, meant that the full path was returned not a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to return a list of files relative from the current directory is to use `xcopy /L`:

```cmd
pushd "%~dp0.."
xcopy /L /S /I ".\Sample" "%TEMP%" | find ".\"
popd
```

To loop through all the returned items, use this:

```cmd
pushd "%~dp0.."
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    xcopy /L /S /I ".\Sample" "%TEMP%" ^| find ".\"
') do (
    echo(%%F
)
popd
```

To remove the `.\` prefix, use the following:

```cmd
pushd "%~dp0.."
for /F "tokens=1* delims=\" %%E in ('
    xcopy /L /S /I ".\Sample" "%TEMP%" ^| find ".\"
') do (
    echo(%%F
)
popd
```